# How do I set up Transparent Proxy on Windows proxy machine?

Tags: android, windows, mitmproxy, transparentproxy

The current documentation on how to set up a transparent proxy does not include Windows: https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-transparent/

I am wondering if someone can please explain to me how to set up Transparent Proxy on my Windows computer?

My ultimate goal is to be able to have Android application data go through mitmproxy.
I originally used Regular proxy, however, I then can not use applications that need the internet.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://serverfault.com/questions/567058/iptables-for-windows-to-redirect-traffic

Comment: `mitmdump.exe --mode transparent` works for me. Strange it is not documented.

Answer (score 0):

I) Enable IP forwarding by opening regedit

1. Navigate to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters"
2. Change IPEnableRouter to 1
   II) Run services->Routing and Remote->start

III) Some say you have to run the py script: https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/libmproxy/platform/windows.py

IV) mitmweb --mode transparent --listen-port 1080 --web-port 8080 --showhost